# How to change last occurrence of the string in the line?

Tags: substitute

I've the following example line:

```
aa ... abc abc abc ... zz
```

I'm aware that `:s/abc/ok/` will change the first occurrence of `abc` in the current line and adding `g` flag will change all of them.

How do I change last occurrence of the string (without knowing how many there are and what's after the last)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Greedy matching:

```
:s/.*\zsabc//
```

The `.*` will consume as many characters as possible (therefore leaving you at the last occurrence), and the `\zs` sets the start of the actual match (`\zs` and `\ze` are useful substitutes for positive lookaheads/lookbehinds in Vim) so that the text before isn't removed as well.